# IF clause or CASE statement in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, if-statement, case

How do I do something like this code below:

```
 SELECT c.TABLE_NAME, c.COLUMN_NAME, c.DATA_TYPE, c.Column_default, c.character_maximum_length, c.numeric_precision, c.is_nullable,
 if(u.CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'PRIMARY KEY')
 Begin
print 'primary key'
 end
else
begin
print ''
end
 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS as c
 LEFT OUTER JOIN information_schema.CONSTRAINT_table_USAGE as u
 ON c.table_name = u.table_name
 Order by table_name
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
 SELECT ..., c.is_nullable,
        CASE WHEN u.CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'PRIMARY KEY' THEN 'primary key'
        ELSE '' 
        END AS KeyType
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS as c
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT
    c.TABLE_NAME, c.COLUMN_NAME, c.DATA_TYPE, c.Column_default,
    c.character_maximum_length, c.numeric_precision, c.is_nullable,
    case
     when u.CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'PRIMARY KEY' then 'primary key'
     else ''
    end as pk
 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS as c
 LEFT OUTER JOIN information_schema.CONSTRAINT_table_USAGE as u
 ON c.table_name = u.table_name
 Order by table_name
```

You can't PRINT inside a SELECT of course

Comment: Msg 102 - you missed THEN on the line that starts with WHEN.